# how do i resend a request after processing it inside my apigee endpoint

Tags: apigee

I have a endpoint called get user data which accepts a token

I need to read this token in my apigee and send it to tokenVarificationExtUrl

which gets back to me with 
a) valid 200 
b) userid attached with that token

now what i have to do is i need to read the response header and then conditionally check it for 200 success and then extract the userid from the response.

Once its extracted i need to attach it with another request; which i need to send to getUserData external url

which will get back to me with required user details.

I am successful of extracting data and doing conditional check. I am seeking help for

how do i send another request to getUserData external url.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a few policies in your proxy.

For example

1. For checking a header and throwing an error, you may want to use rasie fault policy conditionally
2. For making an API call to external end-point you can use service callout policy or a standard target
3. For exrtacting response data from json or xml payload you can use json path of xpath policies

and so on.

I suppose you may want to take a look at a few sample proxies with these functions to be able to design your own.

Check this link out. http://apigee.com/docs/content/using-sample-api-proxies